# How to parse empty node value in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, xml-parsing

I am getting the response from the web service as below

```
<topic id="2"></topic>
<topic id="2">xxx</topic>
```

while parsing the above throws Null pointer exception .This is my code

```
speakersnode=speaker.getElementsByTagName("speaker");
for(int k=0;k<speakersnode.getLength();k++)
{
    ids.addElement(((Element)speakersnode.item(k)).getAttribute("id"));
    System.out.println("speaker "+speakersnode.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    vspeakers.addElement(speakersnode.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
}
```

How can i solve the problem.

Comment: Can you post some code? Why don't you just handle the null as an empty?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
speakersnode=speaker.getElementsByTagName("speaker");
for(int k=0;k<speakersnode.getLength();k++)
{
   ids.addElement(((Element)speakersnode.item(k)).getAttribute("id"));
   String info = speakersnode.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
   if (info == null){
       info = "";
   }     
   System.out.println("speaker "+ info );
   vspeakers.addElement(info);
}
```

You also need to learn how to debug.
And how to handle exceptions.
You will lear how to fix this kind of stuff in seconds

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code it workd

```
speakersnode=speaker.getElementsByTagName("speaker");
for(int k=0;k<speakersnode.getLength();k++)
{
   String info;
    ids.addElement(((Element)speakersnode.item(k)).getAttribute("id"));
   try{
   info = speakersnode.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
  }catch(NullPointerException e){info="";}
  vspeakers.addElement(info);
}
```