# Null pointer exception when parsing Node Value in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse empty node value in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992089/how-to-parse-empty-node-value-in-blackberry)

I am getting the response from web service as below.

```
 <section id="2"></section>
 <section id="2">xxx</section>
```

Now to parse the above response i wrote the code as below

```
speakersnode=speaker.getElementsByTagName("section");
for(int k=0;k<speakersnode.getLength();k++)
{
    System.out.println("speaker "+speakersnode.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    vspeakers.addElement(speakersnode.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
}
```

When i parsing it i am getting null pointer exception here.

Now i chaged the code as follow

```
speakersnode=speaker.getElementsByTagName("section");
for(int k=0;k<speakersnode.getLength();k++)
{
    if(speakersnode.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() !=null)
{
    System.out.println("speaker "+speakersnode.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    vspeakers.addElement(speakersnode.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
}
}
```

But still i am getting the null pointer exception how

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
speakersnode=speaker.getElementsByTagName("speaker");
for(int k=0;k<speakersnode.getLength();k++)
{
   ids.addElement(((Element)speakersnode.item(k)).getAttribute("id"));
   String info = speakersnode.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
   if (info == null){
       info = "";
   }     
   System.out.println("speaker "+ info );
   vspeakers.addElement(info);
}
```

You also need to learn how to debug. And how to handle exceptions. You will lear how to fix this kind of stuff in seconds